# Set initial JQuery suggest value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery suggest box using a key and a value. The key is the saved value, for example a userId and the value is the shown value such as a username.

When having a blank field it works great. I type a few characters, select a name and the value is added as the value that is posted with the HTTP request. Now, how should I prefill a form's suggest with when it already has a value. When placing the saved userId as the value the suggest shows the userId but, obviously I want to show the username. I also tried to echo the username that was selected but than, if the username is not changed the posted value will be the username.

```
                <script>
                <!--
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#creatorUserId").autocomplete("Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=suggest",{
                        parse: function(data) {
                            var parsed = [];
                            data = data.data;

                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                parsed[parsed.length] = {
                                    data: data[i],
                                    value: data[i].key,
                                    result: data[i].value
                                };
                            }

                            return parsed;
                        },
                        formatItem:function(item, index, total, query){
                            return item.value;
                        },
                        formatResult:function(item){
                            return item.id;
                        },
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                });
                -->
                </script>   

<input type="text" name="creatorUserId" id="creatorUserId" value="3" size="40" />
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated the post to include the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
            <!--
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#creatorUserId").autocomplete("Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=suggest",{
                    parse: function(data) {
                        var parsed = [];
                        data = data.data;

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            parsed[parsed.length] = {
                                data: data[i],
                                key: data[i].key,
                                value: data[i].value
                            };
                        }

                        return parsed;
                    },
                    formatItem:function(item, index, total, query){
                        return item.value;
                    },
                    formatResult:function(item){
                        return item.id;
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            });
            -->
            </script>
```

Comment: What is the difference with my Javascript?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen look inside the for loop.Jquery autocomplete expects key, value.But you have given value,result.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the current value of the text box on click (If and only if the text box has not yet been edited).

When the input looses focus, and if the input was un-edited, put the initial value back.

Comment: That would not resolve my issue. The value you is still the key or the username. The user is the one you want to show but never send.